# How to divide value from one row with another

Tags: pandas, dataframe

| ref_area.label | time | cat | obs_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| France | 2018 | old | 26575.796 |
| France | 2018 | worker | 75067.714 |
| France | 2019 | old | 27118.034 |
| France | 2019 | worker | 74956.094 |
| Hong Kong, China | 2018 | old | 2488.000 |
| Hong Kong, China | 2018 | worker | 9912.692 |
| Hong Kong, China | 2019 | old | 2602.402 |
| Hong Kong, China | 2019 | worker | 9882.588 |

I have the following dataframe. How can I find the ratio of workers/old for each country and time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplier is divide pivoted table by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df1 = df.pivot(['ref_area.label','time'], 'cat','obs_value')

df1['ratio'] = df1['worker'].div(df1['old'])
df1 = df1.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df1)
     ref_area.label  time        old     worker     ratio
0            France  2018  26575.796  75067.714  2.824665
1            France  2019  27118.034  74956.094  2.764068
2  Hong Kong, China  2018   2488.000   9912.692  3.984201
3  Hong Kong, China  2019   2602.402   9882.588  3.797487
```

If need original ouput add [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df1 = df.pivot(['ref_area.label','time'], 'cat','obs_value')

df1['ratio'] = df1['worker'].div(df1['old'])
df1 = df1.stack().reset_index(name='obs_value')
print (df1)
      ref_area.label  time     cat     obs_value
0             France  2018     old  26575.796000
1             France  2018  worker  75067.714000
2             France  2018   ratio      2.824665
3             France  2019     old  27118.034000
4             France  2019  worker  74956.094000
5             France  2019   ratio      2.764068
6   Hong Kong, China  2018     old   2488.000000
7   Hong Kong, China  2018  worker   9912.692000
8   Hong Kong, China  2018   ratio      3.984201
9   Hong Kong, China  2019     old   2602.402000
10  Hong Kong, China  2019  worker   9882.588000
11  Hong Kong, China  2019   ratio      3.797487
```